# How to get difference between times only

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime, timespan

I want only time difference between two values, it gives the wrong value when I cross 12 hours.

ex: 6:00 AM and select 7:00 PM then gives result as 660 minute instead of 780.
it works till I select time between 12 hours range.

Please help me to resolve this stuff.

```
Dim sDateStart As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(CType(cboStartHours.SelectedItem, ListItem).ItemText & ":" _
                          & CType(cboStartMins.SelectedItem, ListItem).ItemText & ":00 " _
                          & CType(cboStartAMPM.SelectedItem, ListItem).ItemText)
Dim sDateEnd As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(CType(cboEndHours.SelectedItem, ListItem).ItemText & ":" _
                          & CType(cboEndMins.SelectedItem, ListItem).ItemText & ":00 " _
                          & CType(cboEndAMPM.SelectedItem, ListItem).ItemText)
Dim TS As TimeSpan = sDateEnd - sDateStart

Console.WriteLine(TS.Duration.TotalMinutes)
```

Thank You

Comment: I just tested your code and it works fine with start time 6 AM and end time 7PM. Are you sure cboEndAMPM items are correctly set ?

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to be sure you're dealing with right format

Comment: Yes. actually, it looks like, date is same for both the date object and giving result as -11 for TS.hours. but expecting 13 hours when select 6 to 7. please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the time difference between two `DateTime` values, you can ignore the date part by using `DateTime.TimeOfDay`, which returns a `TimesSpan`.

So you get the difference like so:

```
var diff = sDateEnd.TimeOfDay - sDateStart.TimeOfDay;
```

If the difference is negative, you need to add 24 hours to it (for example, if the start date had a time of 16:00 and the end a time of 09:00 you would get a difference of -07:00. When you add 24 hours to that, you get the correct result of 17:00.

For example:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2014, 01, 01, 16, 0, 0); // In the afternoon of day 1.
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2014, 01, 02, 09, 0, 0); // In the morning of day 2.

var diff = date2.TimeOfDay - date1.TimeOfDay;

if (diff.TotalSeconds < 0)
    diff = diff + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);

Console.WriteLine(diff.TotalHours); // Prints 17
```

If your `DateTime` values are guaranteed to be less than 24 hours apart you can always do this:

```
var diff2 = (date2 - date1); // Much simpler, but needs DateTime values less than a day apart.
```

There is one important question though: What do you want to do if the DateTime values are more than 24 hours apart? What does it mean to produce an answer that is less than 24 hours in that case?

Comment: My input time is in 12 hours format (not in 24 hours).

Comment: @user3711357 DateTime values DO NOT HAVE a format like that. Once you have parsed the data correctly to a `DateTime`, this calculation will work correctly. You just need to plug in the `DateTime` values that you have already obtained in your OP.

Comment: @downvoter: Please indicate what is wrong with this answer, so we can all learn!

Comment: @Shell No, my answer works fine for those dates. Note where I check if the differences is negative and add 24 hours to it if so. Also note the text where I explicitly describe this operation.

Comment: yeah i know that. but, before your ans down voted you haven't described it. but, my question is why are you using `TimeOfDay` when you can deduct time directly using `sDateEnd - sDateStart` and you can get the result in `TimeSpan` object. It can work in 24 hours as well as between two different dates.

Comment: @Shell I've clarified my answer - it ignores the date parts, and always produces an answer less than 24 hours. If indeed the datetime values are less than 24 hours apart, you can use your answer (which is much simpler). If they are more than 24 hours apart, then it's kind of a strange thing to want to calculate, as you point out!

Answer (score 4):

try this also. in VB.Net there is a method that you can use directly to get the difference between two date values in Year/Month/Quarter/Days/Hours/Minutes/Seconds.

```
Dim iMin As Long = DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, sDateStart, sDateEnd)
```

you can find the complete reference and example on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b5xbyt6f(v=vs.90).aspx)

in C#

```
DateTime sDateStart = New DateTime(2014,07,06,18,0,0);   //06-Jul-2014 06:00PM
DateTime sDateEnd = New DateTime(2014,08,08,7,0,0);      //08-Aug-2014 07:00AM
TimeSpan ts = sDateEnd - sDateStart;
int iMin = ts.TotalMinutes;     //Result of ts.TotalMinutes: 46860.0F
```

Comment: +1 This is the best answer if the DateTime values are guaranteed to be less than 24 hours apart.