# What is the difference between deducting two dates directly and deducting TimeOfDay of two days?

Tags: c#, datetime

Recently i have posted an answer where OP wants to get the difference between two times in minutes. I have suggested an answer like this.

My Suggestion

```
DateTime StartDate;
DateTime EndDate;

TimeSpan ts = EndDate - StartDate
int iMin = ts.TotalMinutes;
```

but, there is also another suggestion has given another user who has deducted only TimeOfDay.

```
TimeSpan ts = EndDate.TimeOfDay - StartDate.TimeOfDay
```

and he said that my answer is perfect where **DateTime values are guaranteed to be less than 24 hours apart.**

But, I have tested my code and it can also work when two the date difference are more than a day.

So, I am confused now in what is the difference in both above method?

`EndDate - StartDate` and `EndDate.TimeOfDay - StartDate.TimeOfDay`

Comment: The first calculates the timespan between two dates and the second calculates it only between the time of the same date. The former is the correct way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, I have tested my code and it can also work when two the date
>   difference are more than a day.

There must be an error in your test. It's likely that you are ignoring the Days component of the resulting `TimeSpan` in each case.

Here is a LINQPad sample:

```
var midnightToday = DateTime.Today;
var today2AM = midnightToday.AddHours(2);
var tomorrow2AM = today2AM.AddDays(1);

(tomorrow2AM - midnightToday).Dump("Direct Subtraction");
(tomorrow2AM.TimeOfDay - midnightToday.TimeOfDay).Dump("TimeOfDay Subtraction");
```

The output is:

```
Direct Subtraction 
1.02:00:00 

TimeOfDay Subtraction 
02:00:00
```

Comment: i didn't get any error but, a user has said me that my suggestion needs both dates difference should be less than 24 hours? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238886/how-to-get-difference-between-times-only/25239070#comment39319252_25239070

Comment: Ohh really ! thanks @Ani. But, Which method should i use when i deducting times only? Does it make any difference in performance?

Comment: You should use the method that captures the desired semantics! What result do you *want* when you subtract tomorrow2AM from todayMidnight? 1 day 2 hrs or 2 hrs?

Comment: OK I got it. So, I should use TimeOfDay Subtraction when the two values are less than 24 hours otherwise i should use direct subtraction. Thanks again @Ani

Comment: There's no need to special case the case when "two values are less than 24 hours", is there? I don't understand why you are doing that.

Comment: No there is no such a case like that. Suppose i want to subtract  `06:00 AM` from '05:00 PM` then i can use TimeOfDay subtraction. but, if i have two dates where the date difference is more than a day than i have to use Direct Subtraction. right?

Comment: Correct, but why not just use direct subtraction in all cases? Your requirements aren't clear. Also, you should call timeSpan.Duration() to get the absolute value if that's what you prefer.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `TimeOfDay` removes `Date` part of the `DateTim`e,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.DateTime.TimeOfDay);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true

So both `TimeSpan` are equals providing both StartDate and EndDate have the same Date:

```
  // 11 Aug 2014
  DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 8, 0, 0, 3);   
  DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 8, 23, 59, 56);
```

But different if the Date parts are not the same

```
  // 12 Aug 2014 and 11 Aug 2014
  DateTime StartDate = new DateTime(2014, 11, 8, 23, 59, 59);   
  DateTime EndDate = new DateTime(2014, 12, 8, 0, 0, 44);
```

note, that difference between the values can be *as small as you want* (there's *no guarantee* of the right answer even if the difference of the values less than 24 hours)